# How to fill list in one entity with data from another entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

So, In my Spring Boot APP I have `Transaction` table, so every user can create a transaction and I want to display that transaction on appropriate page on this way:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ecf9.png

I hope you get the format that I want to use. So for example if user create today two transactions show him that transactions, but if user didn't create a transaction yesterday just skip that date and again show date where user had a transactions.

So point is to display a separated dates which have a transactions.

To do something like this I created a separated entity that will hold the date and transactions list. Like this:

```
public class TransactionGroup {
  private LocalDate date;
  private List<Transaction> transactions;
  /* getters and setters */
}
```

In thymeleaf I created something like this:

```
<div th:each="group : ${transactionGroup}">
<h1 th:text="${group.date}" />

<div th:each="transaction : ${group.transactions}">
    <h2>Amount: <span th:text="${transactions.amount}"></span></h2><br>
    <h2>Note: <span th:text="${transactions.note}"></span></h2><br>
    <h2>Wallet name: <span th:text="${transactions.walletName}"></span></h2><br>
    <h2>Expense Category: <span th:text="${transactions.expenseCategories}"></span></h2><br>
    <h2>IncomeCategory: <span th:text="${transactions.incomeCategories}"></span></h2>
<div>
```

Now, this is service to save transaction, inside It I tried to fill the list but I think that is a problem actually of this:

```
 @PostMapping("/saveIncome/{walletId}")
public String saveIncome(@PathVariable(value = "walletId") long walletId, @Valid Transaction transaction, BindingResult result, Model model) {

    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    UserDetailsImpl user = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
    long userId = user.getId();

    Wallet wallet = walletService.getWalletById(walletId);

    TransactionGroup transactionGroup = new TransactionGroup();

    transaction.setWallet(wallet);
    transaction.setUserId(userId);
    transaction.setWalletName(wallet.getWalletName());
    transactionGroup.setTransactions(transaction.getWalletName(), transaction.getAmount(), transaction.getDate(), transaction.getNote(), transaction.getExpenseCategories(), transaction.getIncomeCategories());
    transactionService.saveIncome(transaction, walletId, userId);
    return "redirect:/api/wallet/userWallet/balance/" + userId;
}
```

This is the line from the controller above:

```
transactionGroup.setTransactions(transaction.getWalletName(), transaction.getAmount(), transaction.getDate(), transaction.getNote(), transaction.getExpenseCategories(), transaction.getIncomeCategories());
```

And this is like method inside `TransactionGroup` class:

```
public void setTransactions(String walletName, Double amount, LocalDate date, String note, ExpenseCategories expenseCategories, IncomeCategories incomeCategories) {
}
```

Also, this is controller which is used to show transactions on page:

```
@GetMapping("/userTransactions/{user_id}")
public String getUserTransactions(@PathVariable("user_id") long user_id, Model model) {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    UserDetailsImpl user = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
    long userId = user.getId();
    TransactionGroup transactionGroup = new TransactionGroup();
    model.addAttribute("transactionGroup", transactionGroup);
    model.addAttribute("userId", userId);
    model.addAttribute("transactions", transactionService.findDistinctIdByUserId(user_id));
    return "transactions";
}
```

So when I run the program and go on page where transactions should be page is empty. And I guess there is a problem with filling the list from `TransactionGroup` class but still cannot find a appropriate way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is in the `getUserTransactions` method, with these lines.

```
TransactionGroup transactionGroup = new TransactionGroup();
model.addAttribute("transactionGroup", transactionGroup);
model.addAttribute("transactions", transactionService.findDistinctIdByUserId(user_id));
```

You are creating a new transaction group, and adding that to the model, and then adding your `transactions` attribute separately. But in your html, you are iterating over the transactions that are within a group- `<div th:each="transaction : ${group.transactions}">`.

So you either need to iterate over the transactions property like `<div th:each="transaction : ${transactions}">` or you need to set the transactions property onto the transaction group, and only include the group in your model.

Comment: Thank you, I tried but doesnt work, same resut

Comment: Can you confirm that in your controller the `transactionService.findDistinctIdByUserId(user_id)` is returning data?

Comment: yes it return the data

Comment: Ah I see another problem. You have `transactions` instead of `transaction` within the foreach loop. For example, this line is incorrect- `<h2>Amount: <span th:text="${transactions.amount}"></span></h2><br>`